# Is there a way to get a 'split' function in Haskell to accept two different types of input?

Tags: haskell, split

I am trying to create a function split that can take either [Int] and Int **or** [Char] Char to split either a list of integers on an integer given or split a string on a  character given. I.e.

```
Main> split [1,2,3,0,4,5,0,0,7,8,9] 0
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[7,8,9]]
Main> split "Mary had a little lamb" ' '
["Mary","had","a","little","lamb"]
```

I've tried using Either and (Eq a) but it still doesn't seem to  work. Below is what I've tried doing using class instances but I know very little about this and get the error `Haskell 98 does not support multiple parameter classes`. 
The best way I think I'd understand it would be to use pattern matching or list comprehensions. Any help much appreciated.

```
class Split a where
  split :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a]

instance Split [Char] Char where
  split [] c     = [""]
  split (x:xs) c
    | x == c    = "" : (split xs c)
    | otherwise = (x : head (split xs c)) : tail (split xs c)

instance Split [Int] Int where
  split [] n = []
  split (x:xs) n
    | x == n = [] : (split xs n)
    | otherwise = (x : head (split xs n)) : tail (split xs n)
```

I can get the split function to work with strings and characters but not lists of integers.

Comment: Don't use classes, just write a polymorphic function with the right type e.g. `split :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [[a]]`.

Comment: Perhaps you want to make a `class Split f` with `split :: Eq a => f a -> a -> f a`, then you can define an `instance Split []`.

Comment: Classes were definitely the wrong way to solve this problem - I just included my attempt to try and demonstrate what I was trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a polymorphic function `split`

```
split :: (Eq a) => [a]->a->[[a]]
```

Implementation is simple

```
split [] _    = [[]]
split (x:xs) c
  | x == c    = [] : (split xs c)
  | otherwise = (x : head subSplit) : tail subSplit
        where
           subSplit = split xs c
```

**EDIT**
I suggest different implementation.

```
split :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [[a]]
split x c = map reverse $ split' x c []
   where
      split' :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a] -> [[a]]
      split' [] _ a = [a]
      split' (x:xs) c a 
         | x == c    = a : split' xs c []
         | otherwise = split' xs c (x:a)
```

Comment: subSlit is a typo of subSplit

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just to contribute with an other approach. This solution uses `foldr`. I think it is quite neat but less undestable than @talex's

```
split :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [[a]]
split l c = foldr f acc l
   where acc = [[]]
         f a t@(i@(x:_):xs) = if a == c then []:t else (a:i):xs -- Case when the current accumulator is not empty
--                                           |          |- cons a to current accumulator
--                                           |- start a new accumulator
         f a t@([]:xs)      = if a == c then t    else [a]:xs -- Case when the current accumulator is empty. Usefull when two separators are together
--                                           |          |- cons a to current accumulator
--                                           |- Don't start a new accumulator, just continue with the current
```

Answer (score 1):

Just correct solution.

```
split :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [[a]]                                          
split xs delim = go $ dropWhile (== delim) xs                               
  where                                                                     
    go [] = []                                                              
    go xs = let (tok, rest) = break (== delim) xs                           
             in tok : go (dropWhile (== delim) rest)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data.List.Split.splitOn` (available from the `split` package) is close:

```
> splitOn [0] [1,2,3,0,4,5,0,0,7,8,9]
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[],[7,8,9]]
> splitOn " " "Mary had a little lamb"
["Mary","had","a","little","lamb"]
```

Your `split :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [[a]]` would be

```
split lst d = filter (not.null) $ splitOn [d] lst
```